Чем мем отличается от анекдота?
В чем сходство и различие анекдота и мема?
Из Сети  Поиск Яндекса
Эволюция смеха: от анекдота к мему.
Как устроены мемы и почему они вытесняют анекдоты.
Культура советского анекдота, или советские мемы.
Какая разница между анекдотом и мемом?  И т. д.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Мем - это не совсем жанр. Я бы рассматривал мем как постмодернистский троп, противоположный метафоре.
Анекдот может быть мемичный, а может быть и вполне самодостаточным, но метафорическим. В меме нет метафоричности, там есть ложная эмоциональная посылка рождающее стресс или миниистерику.
Анекдот же изначально, просто запоминающийся любопытный случай, интересная коротка история из жизни, которую можно экстраполировать на что-то другое. То есть анекдот - это чистый модерн. Позже анекдот выделился в отдельный литературный жанр и народное творчество, мультикультурное. А мем - это субкультурное творчество, у мема всегда есть целевая аудитория, а у анекдот общедоступен в целом, даже пошлый анекдот.
По крайней мере русский анекдот такой. Он сталкивает не знания, а культуры восприятия. Для примера два анекдота уровня школьников:

Вовочка 5 минут наблюдал в замочную скважину чем занимаются родители в
спальне. Потом вздохнул и сказал : "И ЭТИ люди запрещают мне
ковыряться в носу!"

То есть конфликт воспитания, родители и дети - сразу вырисовывается ряд общий проблем, это забавно.
А что такое мем?

-Адольфик, вставай, первая мировая война началась!
-Мама, мне ко второй…

"Мне ко второй" тут же становится мемом, почему? Потому что это фраза школьников, но вставленная в ответ Гитлера матери, при этом ситуация полностью сгенерированная, искусственная, вырванная из контекста, оставлены только формальные "мать", "сын" и "мне ко второй". Вся остальная история, которую додумывает мозг, является вымыслом. Это делает фразу мемичной, в противовес вполне первой, вполне реальной истории, где сказанное смысл не меняет, а наоборот, подтверждает.
То есть метафора - утверждает, но более общий смысл. А мем - разрушает и переворачивает смысл, сохраняя значение отдельных элементов, утверждает лжесмысл.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Спасибо за участие в ОЧЕНЬ ИНТЕРЕСНОЙ ДИСКУССИИ!

И вам спасибо.)

Изначально мой ответ дан в комментарии:

Сходство примерно как у сыра и «Титаника»: если посчитать дырки,
может, совпадут. Анекдот — форма, если угодно, жанр, в которой
концовка должна вызывать смех. И нет здесь никакой вирусности: пишите
анекдоты «в стол» — они останутся анекдотами. А мем — явление
массовое, неограниченное формами и целями. Грустная мелодия — тоже
мем. И дуля — мем.

Предлагаю нырнуть в архив научных статей «Киберленинка» и познакомиться с определениями.
Что такое анекдот:

это короткий устный смешной рассказ о вымышленном событии с
неожиданной концовкой, в котором действуют постоянные персонажи,
известные всем носителям языка

Также автор отмечает, что анекдот:

в первичной устной форме выступает наряду с тостами, розыгрышами, шутками, передразниваниями, байками, приветствиями;

во вторичной, условной форме - это его различные письменные фиксации, записи обычно в сборниках, собраниях или специальных сайтах Интернета.


Ж.Б. Абильдинова. Журнал "Филология"
На что обращаем здесь внимание:
Анекдот обязательно:

короткий рассказ,
смешной.

Анекдот не обязательно:

известен двум или более людям.

Что такое мем:

Это единица информации, передающаяся вирусно.

Рассмотрим по пунктам.
Единица — отдельная самостоятельная часть в составе целого (словарь Ожегова)
Информация в контексте разговоров о мемах, согласно Зиновьевой, это:

слово или фраза (но, не рассказ!)
картинка
видео
текст + визуальная часть
мелодия
идея, воплощённая в разных формах

А вирусно — это как?
Вот что пишет Канашина:

Вирусность интернет-мема понимается как его способность быстро
распространятся в интернете и тиражироваться большим количеством копий
среди интернет-пользователей. Механизм распространения интернет-мема
напоминает принцип циркуляции в сети опасных компьютерных вирусов,
поэтому в английском языке существует выражение go viral (букв. «стать
вирусным»), означающее «распространяться с огромной скоростью, стать
популярным», которое часто используется применительно к
интернет-мемам. Кроме того существует английское слово virality,
которое по значению выражает идею вирусности и также часто применяется
к интернет-мемам, но которое в русском языке принято переводить как
«виральность», а не как «вирусность». Термин вирусность представляется
предпочтительным, поскольку создает прямую аналогию с «вирусной»
природой интернет-мема, позволяющей ему мгновенно разлетаться в
пространстве инернета.

Кроме того, автор выделяет ещё и много других свойств:

способность плодить свои подобия,
актуальность,
эмоциональность.

А что насчёт юмора?
Ну, автор отмечает, что если он есть в юморе, то фольклорный, народный, как раз как в анекдоте. НО:

встречаются интернет-мемы без юмористического компонента, апеллирующие
к таким эмоциям, как грусть, тоска, ностальгия и т.д.

Так какие мы выделяем характеристики мема?
Мем обязательно:

известен двум или более людям.

Мем не обязательно:

короткий рассказ (он, скорее, будет словом или фразой, никто не будет воспроизводить рассказы),
смешной.

Полная противоположность анекдоту.
И ещё раз объясню уже на пальцах
Если вы пишите чисто для себя маленькие смешные рассказы и не показываете их ни одному человеку, они всё равно считаются по форме и жанру анекдотами. А стихотворения останутся стихотворениями. Это чисто литературные понятия. Они не зависят от того, сколько их человек прочитали.
Кроме того, анекдоты лишены свойства порождать другие анекдоты. Если вы, услышав вчера анекдот от соседа Васи, добавите туда пару деталей и придёте пересказывать ему, это будет просто плагиат. Никакого одобрения ваше действие не получит (в отличие от ситуации, когда вы дополняете и по-новому обыгрываете чей-то мем).
Но если вы нарисовали смешную картинку и никому её не показали, либо показали ста людям, но им эта картинка не понравилась, она не станет мемом. Мем — это не форма, не жанр. Это информация, к которой у людей складывается одобрительное отношение, которое толкает их на то, чтобы эту информацию воспроизводить.
Если в школе зубастого учителя за глаза школьники дразнят Шелкунчиком, это уже локальный мем школы. Он имеет одобрение определённой социальной группы и быстро распространяется среди единомышленников, не забываясь, а каждый раз по-новому обыгрываясь.
Если кафе в вашем городе стали назвать Бухляшкой, и это очень быстро подхватила большая часть населения, то это уже городской мем.
Если смешная картинка из интернета научила вас добавлять «Карл» к некоторым фразам, чтобы заострить на них внимание, то это проекция в вашу жизнь мема — информационной единицы, фразы, чей контекст вам понятен сейчас, в рамках духа времени.
И для мема важен контекст. Анекдот может быть понятен и самодостаточен сам по себе. А мем опирается на определённую осведомлённость людей, их вовлечённость в общую культурную среду, будь это знание фильма, истории, взаимоотношений ваших друзей или преданий внутри вашей семьи.
И в определении мема нет ничего, требующего от него чего-то смешного. Мем может быть грустным комментарием к актуальным негативным событиям. Например, утка, которая говорит "всё плохо".

Ещё раз призываю спрашивать нормальные вещи, а не искать очевидную разницу между метлой и самоваром. Подобные вопросы буду минусовать. И считаю это справедливым. Обижайтесь, не обижайтесь, а форум должен держать определённую планку.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
